# How to take screenshot in Cocos2D iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to take a screen shot using the following command but it gives me warning and did not worked for me.  I am using cocos2d version 2.0

```
UIImage *image = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] screenshotUIImage];
```

Please suggest me that what is the solution of that command so that it works perfectly.

Comment: @Manthan He posted the code

Comment: Put some efforts by searching on net before asking question here

Comment: I have tried to capture the whole screen and just run that code on a button press... Basically i want to capture the screen for sharing purpose. I have convert UIImage to CCSprite to crop that image. As, I did not get the image thats why i can't do any further process on that.

Comment: UIImage *image = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] screenshotUIImage]; This has been depricated. I think mod should lock this one. Its not useful anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a method and use it as shown below

You can use this.

```
+(UIImage*) screenshotWithStartNode:(CCNode*)stNode
{
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    CCRenderTexture* renTxture = 
    [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width 
                                 height:winSize.height];
    [renTxture begin];
    [stNode visit];
    [renTxture end];

    return [renTxture getUIImage];
}
```

Call like this

```
CCScene *myScene = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
CCNode *node = [myScene.children objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage *img = [AppController screenshotWithStartNode:node];
```

Comment: copy-paste of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413460/cocos2d-2-0-screenshots-on-ios-6. Prefer giving credit where credit is due.

Comment: had used this code months ago not copy - pase... Yeah it took efforts finding the code & editing for better understand.

Comment: CCDirector is deprocated. I am using Director but I am getting error that its not objective C class. :/ any clue