# CCRenderTexture's renderTextureWithWidth fails to compile in cocos2d v3.2.1+

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to use cocos2d to take a screenshot of the current scene. Working off of [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26025359/5099203), I translated it over to Swift, and got this:

```
func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage {
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().nextDeltaTimeZero = true

    let viewSize: CGSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().viewSize()
    let renderTexture: CCRenderTexture = CCRenderTexture.renderTextureWithWidth(viewSize.width, height: viewSize.height)

    renderTexture.begin()
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().runningScene.visit()
    renderTexture.end()

    return renderTexture.getUIImage()
}
```

However, I get a compiler error on:

```
let renderTexture: CCRenderTexture = CCRenderTexture.renderTextureWithWidth(viewSize.width, height: viewSize.height)
```

It says "cannot invoke 'renderTextureWithWidth' with an argument list of type '(CGFloat, height: CGFloat)'".

I checked the `CCRenderTexture.h` file, and it says:

```
+(instancetype)renderTextureWithWidth:(int)w height:(int)h;
```

I tried type casting the `viewSize.width` and the `viewSize.height` to `Int`, but it still gave the same "cannot invoke" error again.

Anyone know why this is the case and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These type conversions can be tricky. But if you use the default Swift constructor `CCRenderTexture(width: Int32, height: Int32)` and not the objective-c factory method (the one you tried to use) auto completion will help you out. You need to cast to `Int32` .

Comment: Simple and straightforward solution. Thanks so much for the help - it works like a charm.

Comment: Glad it helped! Perhaps I should have mentioned that whenever you see an objective-c `int`, you can/should use the Swift type `CInt` — which simply is a type alias of `Int32`, but perhaps easier to remember. So, you could have used that here. See the docs for more info:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_11